# Windows Remote Desktop Connection connects to another server

Tags: windows-server-2012, remote-desktop

First off I am not a system/server admin but would like to know why the below happens.

I have a windows 2012 server lets call it 'server01.corp.com'.
and there is another windows 2012 server lets call it 'server02.corp.com'.

When I try to connect 'server01.corp.com' through Remote desktop connection it gives me a login box and then after successful input it shows a Warning box saying 'Identity of remote computer cannot be verified.Do you want to connect anyway?' and their it also says "Name of certificate from remote computer as 'server02.corp.com'" (weird).

So, I click on 'Yes' meaning connect despite these certificate error.

Now comes the next weird part, Instead of connecting to 'server01.corp.com' (which was my intention) it connects to 'server02.corp.com'!!

Although title bar of remote desktop connection says i am connected to 'server01.corp.com' it login me into 'server02.corp.com'!

How is that possible?

Edit: we had to use 'server01.corp.com /admin' in remote desktop connection, it takes us to correct server!

Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two servers - server01 and server02 - which are part of a RDS Farm. One of them (or a totally separate server) is a broker. When you connect to either server01 or server02, the server you are connecting to first has you log on, then consults the broker database to find if you already have a session on one of the two servers, if so, it sends you to that server. If not, it sends you to the "least busy" server (If I remember right, it's by # of users).

That's why you get this. The bar at the top of the RDP window shows the name you use in initiating the connection.

If you had a DNS entry called "rdp" for example, and that was pointing to either one of your server, or a round robin DNS entry with both, or point it to your broker, then you would see "rdp" in the bar, regardless of whether you have a session on server01 or server02.

Using `mstsc /v server01 /admin` logs you on with a Admin Console, and does not consult the broker database. Only administrators of the server can connect using the `/admin` option.

Comment: thanks for the answer ETL :)
what is the purpose of this approach?. I mean server01 & server 02 are two different servers. Can you think of any reason why this is done? I feel it adds complexity (complexity itself adds confusion)

Comment: This is done when you want to balance the load between servers - for example, you provide a RDP service to users, to scale, you add multiple servers. If each servers are for different purpose, then you don't want to enable load balancing with a broker, but if they are the same purpose, it's the best.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds a bit like a DNS issue.  Are the DNS entries for the servers Static, or Dynamic ?  Do you have an alias in place, re-directing the first server to the second ?

Comment: we had to use 'server01.corp.com /admin' in remote desktop connection, it takes us to correct server

Comment: do you think it could be problem with DNS?

Comment: It's always DNS.

Comment: @mfinni - really? no it's definitely not "always DNS" that's really not true...

Comment: @wenn32 see my answer, it's not a DNS issue.